# How to implement a GPIO interrupt handler for x86 linux?

Tags: linux, x86, kernel, driver

I am working on a device driver for x86 linux. The device has a pin connected to GPIO on PCH to generate an interrupt. How do I request for the IRQ associated with that GPIO pin and install the interrupt handler?

Comment: http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch10.pdf may help you.

Comment: @user35443 How go I know the IRQ number to request for?

Comment: Have you seen `gpio_to_irq()`? Is your driver this one? http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/gpio-pch.c

Comment: I'll write it to answer.

Answer (score 6):

The header file you're looking for is

```
#include <linux/gpio.h>
```

The first thing you need to do is to allocate specific GPIO. You can do it using this call:

```
#define GPIO //gpio number

...

if(gpio_request(GPIO, "Description"))
    //fail
    ...
```

After you get the GPIO pin for yourself, you can acquire an IRQ for it

```
int irq = 0;
if((irq = gpio_to_irq(GPIO)) < 0 /*irq number can't be less than zero*/)
    //fail
    ...
```

Now you register an IRQ handler using the usual kernel routines.

```
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
...
int result = request_irq(irq, handler_function, 
                         IRQF_TRIGGER_LOW, /*here is where you set up on what event should the irq occur*/
                         "Description", "Device description");
if(result)
    //fail
    ...
```

Remember to `free_irq` and `gpio_free` when doing module cleanup. If you don't do it, you won't be able to allocate that GPIO pin again.

Comment: How does the GPIO number is mapped to virtual address?
The kernel deals with virtual address right?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit more clear?
GPIOs accessible throught memory mapped IO have their (let's say physical) address set for specific processor/development board. Because most of linux kernel releases use MMU, you must first map that ´physical´ address to a virtual address for your process. After that you access virtual address wherever it is, but your reads and writes are performed on GPIOs.

Comment: Okay, let me be more specific. There is an external interrupt being generated every 10ms at the falling edge of GPIO39 (Pin 22 of the J3 expansion connector in the Panda board, OMAP4460). I've followed exactly the same steps as you have given in your answer to handle the interrupt. But, the handler is not being called. In other words, the interrupt is not being detected at the GPIO39. And one more thing... The IRQ number specified for GPIO39 is 30 in the TRM. But, the return value of gpio_to_irq is 199. Am I missing something? Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: I hope you didn't directly set `GPIO` to be `39`. You must use predefined numbers from kernel's header. You can find some inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213044/948909

Comment: Oh! I've used #define GPIO 39 and passed the MACRO GPIO to both of the APIs gpio_request() and gpio_to_irq().
How do I know the function similar to S3C64XX_GPP() for Pandaboard ES OMAP4460 ?

Comment: You must, as written in the post, check `arch` directory in linux sourcecode.